# Custom xilinx zynq board (MYIR) kernel starting hung

Tags: linux-kernel, xilinx, freeze, zynq

I have a custom zynq board(MYC-C7Z010/20 CPU Module) and compile original u-boot+Linux 3.15.0 for it succesfully and it works fine. But I try to update my kernel with this git repository https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx.
I add my board defconfig file to kernel/arch/arm/config path and build kernel succesfully without any error. All of my commands are like this

```
$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi- distclean
$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi- zynq_myd_defconfig
$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi- -j 4 LOADADDR=0x00008000 uImage 
$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi- dtbs
```

but ofter that i will see only kernel starting ..
i try to help google and find sevral issue about this.

- I enable Kernel low level debug from this tutorial http://embeddedbuzz.blogspot.com/2012/01/enabling-low-level-kernel-debugging-and.html?m=1
- I enable debuging port to xillinx UART0 in menuconfig
- I change bootargs like this console=ttyPS0,115200 root=/dev/ram rw earlyprintk:serial

but nothing changed with me. Only last message and without any other help.

I need your step by step help if help me.

Also it may be good if I can check u-boot and kernel MACHINE ID for sure problem is not from these.

Comment: I change Kernel low level debug port to Xilinx UART1 and take this error "Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel." and hang again!

Answer (score 0):

I find solution myself and load new kernel successfully. in first step i edit menuconfig and enable *Kernel low level debug module and select Xilinx UART1 as terminal out put in *Kernel low level debug port. also i enable *early printk and select debug level to 7 in *printk and dmesg option.

after compiling my kernel i receive new error related to [this](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/7-Series-FPGAs/Starting-kernel-get-stuck-zynq-early-efuse-init-no-efuse-node/td-p/757909) document. after to resolve it my kernel ran exactlly and now i enjoy new kernel in my MYD0702 board.

for next usage i push my edited kernel in [This](https://github.com/mfarahaniasl/linux-xlnx-myir) repository.